# Added .FBX doesn't follow armature "head" bone

Tags: rigging, export, edit-mode

(newbie here)

I have an rigged character and I am trying to add additional .FBX props on top of that.

**Steps followed:**

1. Import FBX prop (a branch in this case)
2. Add Armature modifier and linked it to the Rig and Checked "Bind it to Vertex Groups"
   [image]
3. Create a new vertex group for the newly added prop and add it to "head" (named exactly as my head bone)
   [image]
4. Moved the SM_Tree_Twing_02 under Head object in tree (I don't know if this matters, though)

**The problem:**
If I try to rotate the "head" bone in Pose mode, my prop doesn't follow the bone rotation.
Normal Pose:
[image: Normal Pose:]

With rotated bone:
[image: With rotated bone:]

What am I missing?
I'm sure I'm missing something because if I try to export to Unity I get the branch follow my character and has movement on it (it is linked to something from my Armature). Thank you for your input. I don't mind going to read how it is done but frankly I do not know what exactly to search for.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. The problem is that you did not parent the object to the armature. Simply adding an armature modifier will not make the object move with the armature. To parent, select the object, then the rig, and press CTRL-P, then armature deform.

Comment: This solution work great in Blender. But I'm not sure if constraints are exported to Unity. I wan't to take my character in Unity. Is there any way to combine a prop with an existing rigged mesh other than re-creating it in the mesh?

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix was to remove all bones from "head" up and re-assign all the meshes with new weights. This worked for me. I'm not sure why I had to do this again, tho.